# Unexpected identifier [object Object]

Tags: javascript, object, identifier

```
var costBusRoute = 600;
var busRoute = 0;
var vehCountBus = 0;
var routesBus = [{number:0, vehCount:0}];
var maintBus = 50;

function newBusRoute() {
    busRoute += 1;
    routesBus.push({number:busRoute, vehCount:0});
    viewRoutes(routesBus, "busRoutes", busRoute);
}

function newBus(routenum) {
    vehCountBus += 1;
    routenum.vehCount += 1;
    capacity += 50;
    bank -= 600;
    checkBank();
    checkCapacity();
    eiv += 99;
    checkEIV();
    updateVehNum(routenum);
}

function viewRoutes(routelist, listhtml, routenum) {
    document.getElementById(listhtml).innerHTML = "";
    for (I in routelist) {
        nameList = "<li class='list'><button onclick='editRoute("+routelist+","+routelist[routenum]+")'>" + routelist[I].number + "</button></li>";
        document.getElementById(listhtml).innerHTML += nameList;
    }
}

function editRoute(routelist, routenum) {
    $("#mainContainer").fadeOut();
    document.getElementById("screen").innerHTML = (
        "<h1>Bus Route " + routelist[routenum].number + "</h1>" +
        "<div id='vehicleNum'><p>Vehicles on this route: " + routelist[routenum].vehCount + "</div>" +
        "<p><button onclick='newBus("+routelist[routenum].number+")'>+ Add Vehicle | £600</button><p>Maintenance: £50 per day" +
        "<p><button onclick='delBus("+routelist[routenum].number+")'>- Remove Vehicle</button>" +
        "<p><button onclick='delRoute("+routelist[routenum].number+")'>- Delete Route</button>"
    );
}
```

I have searched for hours but haven't been able to work out why this throws an error or how to resolve it. Any advice is greatly appreciated!

I'm trying to send the right element from `routesBus` to `editRoute()` so that it can edit the key values in that specific element. The error occurs at `editRoute()` and is shown in the console as `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier`.

Comment: Hey Kiran! How are you?
Could you please edit your question and explain better what you want, and where the error is happening?
You can always just copy the error message from the console

Comment: It's hard for us to guess which line is throwing the error. Which line is it?

Comment: Hi! Could you maybe add a few more informations from the console? It should say in which line the error is occurring.

Comment: I'm guessing its the line that starts with:  `nameList = "<li class='list'>`.  Looks like you're trying to concatenate an object `routelist` into your HTML string.  You can't concatenate an object with a string like that.

Comment: My bad. Let me add that in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think there are various problems:

1. As stated in the comments, you try to add the array as a parameter just by concatenating it directly...and the rest of the parameters as well.

```
nameList = "<li class='list'><button onclick='editRoute("+routelist+","+routelist[routenum]+")'>" + routelist[I].number + "</button></li>";
```

All you get is is string like :

```
<li class='list'><button onclick='editRoute([object Object],[object Object]...
```

2. In addition to that, `editRoute` expects an `array` (`routelist`) and a `number` (`routenum`), the index of the item in the array and when you call it, you (attempt to) give the array and the item, not the index.
3. In `viewRoutes`you use both the index `routenum` given as parameter and the index `I` in the same line. This is inconsistent. You should give up the first one since you are building the whole list and the `routenum` index seems to be useless here. It could be useful if when building the list, you would like to do something special when `I == routenum` (set the text in bold, use a specil color or icon...).

To fix 1 & 2, I would rather use the index as the unique parameter of your `editRoute` function because you can build the html calling it more easily and because the parameter `routelist` corresponds to `routesBus`which is available from `editRoute`.

```
var costBusRoute = 600;
var busRoute = 0;
var vehCountBus = 0;
var routesBus = [{number:0, vehCount:0}];
var maintBus = 50;

function newBusRoute() {
    busRoute += 1;
    routesBus.push({number:busRoute, vehCount:0});
    viewRoutes("busRoutes");
}

function newBus(routenum) {
    vehCountBus += 1;
    routenum.vehCount += 1;
    capacity += 50;
    bank -= 600;
    checkBank();
    checkCapacity();
    eiv += 99;
    checkEIV();
    updateVehNum(routenum);
}

function viewRoutes(listhtml) {
    let nameList  = "";
    for (I in routelist) {
        nameList += `<li class='list'><button onclick='editRoute(${routenum})'>${routesBus[I].number}</button></li>`;

    }
    document.getElementById(listhtml).innerHTML = nameList;
}

function editRoute(routenum) {
    $("#mainContainer").fadeOut();
    let route = routesBus[routenum];
    let number = route.number; //isn't always route.number === routenum?
    // TODO use template literal for the following
    document.getElementById("screen").innerHTML = (
        "<h1>Bus Route " + number + "</h1>" +
        "<div id='vehicleNum'><p>Vehicles on this route: " + route.vehCount + "</div>" +
        "<p><button onclick='newBus("+ number +")'>+ Add Vehicle | £600</button><p>Maintenance: £50 per day" +
        "<p><button onclick='delBus("+ number + ")'>- Remove Vehicle</button>" +
        "<p><button onclick='delRoute(" + number  + ")'>- Delete Route</button>"
    );
}
```

Note that I used [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) on viewRoutes, you should use it as often as you can. Check lso the other places I have changed.
Another thing: since you are using JQuery, your rather learn it a bit, especially [`.click()`](https://api.jquery.com/click/) and how to append elements with it, which would be a big improvement.

Comment: thank you for responding! I've taken a poke around my code as per your advice, but to no avail. I get the feeling that there is one single thing wrong with the code which is throwing everything else out. I think it's the problem of the concatenation. How would I go about solving that? I've tried converting the array and array index to strings but that threw the same error.

Comment: @KiranEvans The error you mentioned is due to the concatenation but I wouldn't say this is the only problem in your code. If you REALLY want to keep your parameters, you can use JSON.stringify() but I think it is a terrible idea.

Comment: Thank you for your advice. I really appreciate it. Despite your warnings, JSON.stringify() actually works for my code.

Comment: @KiranEvans You are welcome but I really suggest you to make en effort to really solve the issues and not chose the easiest solution otherwise you'll pay it later.

Comment: You are right. I've managed to solve one of the issues thanks to your advice already!